# Very slow product listing issue with magento CE

Tags: magento-1.8, product-list

I have a category called **new arrivals** which has 5 subcategories. I created a custom view called new-arrivals.phtml. I created custom Static Block with the following code in magento

```
{{block type="core/template" template="custom/new-arrivals.phtml"}}
```

then from Category setting I changed the display setting>CMS Block to the this cms block that I created. And the **display mode** is **static block only**

This view bring all the subcategories of New Arrivals(Bags, Tops, Shoes etc..) with it's products.. [Like on this website](http://www.gojane.com/new-styles.html)   As you can see on this website it is very fast but on my website with my code it is not. [Here it is...](https://www.punkyfish.com/new-arrivals.html)

How can I make this load faster. Cache and everything is enabled. I assume that there is something wrong with my code. thank you for your help.

and this is new-arrivals.phtml content:

Magento CE 1.8.1

```
<?php
            //I load all the subcategories here
            $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
            $categories = $category->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
                    ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
            ?>

                <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
                    <div class="page-title category-title">
                        <h1>
                            <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>">
                            <span><?php echo $category->getName() ?></span>
                            </a>
                        </h1>
                        <?php
                            // here I load all the products for each category      
                            $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');                  
                            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
                            $_productCollection = $category->getProductCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category)
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search
                            ->addAttributeToSort('date_added', 'ASC');

                        ?>
                         <div class="product-count"><?php echo $count; ?> <?php echo $this->__('Products'); ?></div>
            <?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
            <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
            <?php else: ?>
            <div class="category-products">    


                <?php // Grid Mode ?>
                <?php
                    $_span = 'span3';
                    $_grid_pro = 4;
                ?>

                <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
                <?php $_columnCount = $_grid_pro; //$this->getColumnCount(); ?>
                <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
<?php // all the others stuff ....... ?>
```

Comment: Hosting, always hosting, try using a figure of 1-2% of gross profit margin for you hosting - and use a specialist. Sparse information - you did not provide number of products in your site, hosting level - all guesswork.

Comment: only God knows what you did there, run Aoe_Profiler, at least...

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing untoward in your code - only a single model load, nothing else in a loop. It should load in an instant.

Baseline performance is driven by server configuration, your template performance will be in addition to that.

So I'd recommend starting by changing your hosting provider from UKFast to a company that know's something about Magento - they are arguably one of the slowest/incapable "Magento hosts" in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

There's one other thing you can try out -- check the SQL query itself using `var_dump((string)$collection->getSelect());`. It usually gives pretty good idea what is going on and what can be improved.

Comment: where should I write this code? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually instead of doing that, we associate/deassociate the products with a category or categories via a script, will solve many of your problems.